# RabbitMQ: a new management user cannot see anything

Tags: rabbitmq

I have installed RabbitMQ management console and can login as guest. Nevertheless, I would like to create a new user dedicated to management purpose.

Therefore, I refer to the step 5 of the tutorial (http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/10/enable-rabbitmq-management-plugin/).

1. Login as guest and create a user in the management console with a management tag like this:

   [image]
2. Logout guest and login as guest2.

   However, guest2 can only see the screen like this:
   [image]

There is almost nothing to click or use.

Do I miss something to set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, 
This is a little anomaly on the UI management.

If you see the `URL` you are trying to access to `http://localhost:15672/#/users` and your user can't access.

Try use this `URL` http://localhost:15672

Or just click to the RabbitMQ image